# How to change the background color of textboxes in listview in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox

I have two listviews with textboxes in it. I want to change the background color of textbox if the textbox values are different after loading. How to do it?

Sample XAML is

```
<ListView Name="lstBase">
  <ListView.View>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBox Name="txtBase" Text="{Binding BaseText}" Width="160" BorderThickness="0.5" BorderBrush="Black"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
<ListView Name="lstTarget">
  <ListView.View>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBox Name="txtTarget" Text="{Binding TargetText}" Width="160" BorderThickness="0.5" BorderBrush="Black"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: post your code and XAML.

Comment: <ListView Name="lstBase">
<ListView.View>
<DataTemplate>
<TextBox Name="txtBase" Text="{Binding BaseText}" Width="160" BorderThickness="0.5" BorderBrush="Black"/>
</DataTemplate>
</ListView .View>
</ListView>

<ListView Name="lstTarget">
<ListView.View>
<DataTemplate>
<TextBox Name="txtTarget" Text="{Binding TargetText}" Width="160" BorderThickness="0.5" BorderBrush="Black"/>
</DataTemplate>
</ListView .View>
</ListView>

Comment: please update it with your question ?

Comment: I need to compare the values in textbox and change the bg color if they don't match.How to compare the textbox values if they are in different listviews?

Comment: Textbox has `Background` property for that. And for comparing thing, you should do it in code-behind.

Comment: You can use a IValueConverter, simply pass both the textbox's text, and return a background colour depending on whether they are equal or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <ListView>
            <TextBox Background="black" Height="20" Width="90"/>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.